# Build a function that take CSV as argument and returns dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to build a fuction that gets a csv file as an argument and return a dict without using pandas or any other tool like that.
What Im trying to do is get a dictionary that the keys are country names and the values are the number of medals they got in the olympics (if they didnt got any it should return 0).
this is what I tried to do (don't know how to put it in a function).

```
def summer_olympic_stats(file):
summer_olympic_medals = {}
with open("summer_olympics_countries.csv", "r+") as my_csv:
        for line in my_csv:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            medals = line.startswith("Gold") or line.startswith("Silver") or line.startswith("Bronze") or line.startswith("Total")
            country = row[1]
            country,medals = line.split("\t")
            summer_olympic_medals[country] = int(medals)
print(summer_olympic_stats(open("summer_olympics_countries.csv")))
```

the error code I get is:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'summer_olympics_countries.csv'
```

example for the result I want to get:

```
{'ALG': {'Gold': 5, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 8, 'Total': 17}}
```

just for clarification the csv file looks like that:
[image]

I know that my func is not even close to the solution but I dont really know how to approach it, It's my third week using python so those are my first steps in this world.
Appreciate all the help, Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean: `open("summer_olympics_countries.csv", "r")`?

Comment: thats worked for the error, thanks! Ill try again

Comment: Opening in mode "r+" should work as well, but since there can be file writing involved in that mode, you have to close down the file you want to open other wise you get that permission denied error

i.e. you cant have the data opened up in excel while running the script

Comment: you could add example data as text or eventually as link to file - and then we can test code on data.

Answer (score 0):

Read [How CSV data is represented](https://www.guru99.com/python-csv.html#:%7E:text=csv%20as%20below.-,CSV%20Data,-Programming%20language%2C%20Designed) (Till the part before Python CSV module should be enough) for help:

```
def summer_olympic_stats(file):
    summer_olympic_medals = {}
    with open(file, "r") as my_csv:
        data = my_csv.read().split("\n") # data is now a list, where each element is a line from the csv file

        # We want to find the index of country, gold medal, silver medal and bronze medal
        # So we can use the same indices to get their number
        country_index = 0
        gold_index = 0
        silver_index = 0
        bronze_index = 0

        headings = data[0].split(",")
        
        for heading in headings:
            if "Country" == heading:
                country_index = headings.index(heading)
            elif "Gold" == heading:
                gold_index = headings.index(heading)
            elif "Silver" == heading:
                silver_index = headings.index(heading)
            elif "Bronze" == heading:
                bronze_index = headings.index(heading)

        for line in data[1:]: # The first line is only headings and we dont need to iterate over that
            line = line.split(",") # Divides the line into list containing its components
            
            # Update dictionary in required format, with the help of country_index, gold_index, silver_index, bronze_index
            summer_olympic_medals.update({
                line[country_index] : {
                    "Gold": line[gold_index],
                    "Silver": line[silver_index],
                    "Bronze": line[bronze_index]
                }
            
            })
        
        return summer_olympic_medals
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand it a little bit better now... however the output from your solution give this:
`{'1': {'Gold': '1', 'Silver': '1', 'Bronze': '1', 'total': '1'},`
while the output should be:
`'{'ALG': {'Gold': 5, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 8, 'Total': 17}}'`

Comment: @ranbar fix: `country_index = heading.index(heading)` to `country_index = headings.index(heading)` . heading.index to heading*s*.index(). Same for the other 3 in the `for heading in headings` loop. Fixed in the original answer as well, Not sure how that happened. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas to import csv

```py
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("path")

#create a dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': data["col1"],
                   'col2': ["col2"]},
                  index=['row1', 'row2'])

#create dictionary from dataframe
req_dict = "df.to_dict()"
```

Comment: thanks, but Im trying to solve it without using pandas